# SQL BETWEEN DATES SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: sql

This works...

```
select * 
from events 
where user_id = 47 
  and event_date Between #03/01/2015# And #03/31/2015#
```

But I get a syntax error when the month Is February or any other EVEN number.

```
select * 
from events 
where user_id = 47 
  and event_date Between #02/01/2015# And #02/31/2015#
```

Error:

> Syntax error in date in query expression 'user_id = 57 and event_date Between #02/01/2015# And #02/31/2015#

Can't for the life of me figure out why ??

I'm using an Access database and has been working fine for 3 years up until today, possibly saved in a later version of Access to the original.

Comment: February has 28 days, so you use a date inexistent

Comment: `#03/01/2015#` is an invalid constant for a date in (standard) SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Looks like MS Access to me.

Comment: ***WHAT*** database??? This is **not** the same across all those databases that use **SQL** as their query language - which database are you talking about??

Comment: As good practice I always use cast or convert functions to be sure that the syntax is correct. 
But still February doesn't have 31 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you know `feb has 28 days`: Use

```
select * from events 
where user_id = 47 and event_date 
Between #02/01/2015# And #02/28/2015#
```

Even if you tried at least 29 (You may thought Leap day), It is acceptable. But how comes 31.

Comment: Yes of course ! Was driving me insane ! Its been working for years but just suddenly stopped, possibly after saving in a different version of access.

Comment: No, problem. From now, use 28 days for feb. 29 days for leap day.

Answer (score 3):

February doesn't have 31 days.